# QlikView count displaying wrong value after using left join script

Tags: join, left-join, qlikview

I have a big excel file containing all data I have since 2 years. But to make comparison, there is a field called IAP which is a number that defines a set of rows into single number according to specific date

Per example, all data collected in December 2016 have an IAP of 34, Data collected in January 2017 is 35, and so on.

In this table I need to compare points from different IAP, that was good and turn to be bad in the last IAP (In this case the IAP 37)

Again, if the Status of a point in IAP 34 is good, and turn to be bad in IAP 37, should be counted.

By creating some excel filters and using VLOOKUPS to count that criteria (again points that was good and turn bad in the last added IAP), the result was 100, but in the QlikView the result displayed in a text object is 60.

Here is the script usign Left Join, in the script editor first:

```
NewlyBad:
Load 
Code As Code1 ,
Status as NewStatus , 
New_Sites as NewNew_Sites,
IAP as IAMP_NAME

Resident ALLIAP

where IAP_Version = $(vMaxIAP) ;

Left Join

Load Code as Code1 ,
Status as OldStatus,
IAP as LAST_IAP

Resident ALLIAP
where IAP_Version = $(vMaxIAMP)-3;
```

I used this line `where IAP_Version = $(vMaxIAMP)-3;` to compare data between the last IAP and the IAP-3.

In the variable Overview, I am getting the correct values: comparison between 34 and 37.

Now, the expression of the text object is:

```
=(count ({< NewStatus={"Bad"}, OldStatus-={"Bad"} >} distinct Code1))
```

The result displayed is 60 instead of 100, which wrong.

Comment: maybe I miss the point, but why are you joining by "code1" and not "IAP_Version"? or "code1" and "IAP_Version"? what is "code1"? I think we need some data samples.
in your left join add "IAP_Version-3 as IAP_Version" maybe this will do the trick?

Comment: the code is unique identifier in each IAP_Version, but we can find it in all other IAP_Version so I am joining based on it.

Comment: did you try my suggestion? "in your left join add "IAP_Version-3 as IAP_Version" maybe this will do the trick? "

Comment: Where to add it ?

Comment: Left Join

Load Code as Code1 ,
IAP_Version-3 as IAP_Version,
Status as OldStatus,
IAP as LAST_IAP